# Equivalence classes in $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

I've the following exercise:

Solve each of the following equations in the given set $\mathbb{Z}_n$:

1) $[5]+x=[1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_9$

2) $[2]\cdot x=[7]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

For 1), is $x=5$ right?

For 2), is $x=7$ right?

Comment: why do you think x=7 for second equation?

Comment: I'd made 2*(7)=14...

Comment: You should multiply $7$ by inverse of $2$ in $Z_{11}$ because $[2]^{-1}[2]x = x  = [2]^{-1}[7]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is right as $5 + 5 =10$ is indeed congruent to $1$ modulo $9$ (the division of $10$ by $9$ leaves remainder $1$).

The second is not right as $2 \cdot 7 =14$ and $14$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $11$ and not to $7$. To help solve the second note that $18$ is congruent to $7$ modulo $11$.

Answer (score 0):

Write equations in the congruence form
$$
5+x\equiv1\pmod9\iff x\equiv{-4}\equiv5\pmod9
$$
and for the second one
$$
x\equiv 6(2x)\equiv6(7)\equiv42\equiv9\pmod{11}
$$

Comment: Hence the second solution is x=9?

Comment: Yes, $9$ and every integer congruent to it modulo 11.

Comment: Wait a moment, but isn't x=3...